# Firebase Hostingでリダイレクト処理ができない

Tags: firebase, reactjs

Firebase Hostingを用い、React(ルーティングにはreact-router-domを使用)にてWEBアプリを公開しようとしています。basic認証を行いたいのですが、index.htmlを起点としたSPAなので、cloud functionsを通してルーティング処理をしようとしていますが、うまくいきません。

実装の内容としては以下リンクにあるような「basic-auth-connect」を用いたものです。
https://gist.github.com/mkamakura/c7a57bd1bf64b017f180573adf8ba3d8

firebase.json

```
{    
"hosting": {
  "public": "build",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "redirects": [{
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "/auth"
  }],
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**",
    "function": "app"
  }]
}}
```

cloud functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth-connect')

const app = express()

app.use(basicAuth('username', 'password'))

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/index.html')
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

firebaseのfunctionsのコンソールからログを確認してみると、そもそもリダイレクトしてfunctionsの関数を通っていないようなのですが、ルーティング処理が上手くいないのは何が原因なのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。